# Long to wide with no unique key

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have this dataset:

```
VAR=       c('X1','X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X3','X3','X3','X3','X3')
Ranking=   c(1,2.5 ,2.5   ,1.5  ,1.5  ,NA, 1   ,NA    ,NA   ,1.5  ,1.5  ,3)
df<-data.frame(VAR,Ranking)
```

For which even if I add a unique identifier and spread

```
df$row <- 1:nrow(df)
df_wide<-spread(df, VAR, Ranking)
df_wide<-df_wide[,-1]
```

I don't get what I am after.

[image: This is what I get]

But what I need is:

[image]

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can do this easily with `data.table` `dcast(setDT(df), rowid(VAR)~VAR)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in R base:

```
spl <- split(df, df$VAR)
n <- max(sapply(spl, nrow))
do.call(cbind, lapply(spl, function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x$Ranking),'Ranking']
  length(x) <- n
  x}))
```

Comment: You're right to go with `base` ... I made the assumption of `tidyverse` components based on the use of `spread`. This is also ~10x faster, based on `microbenchmark(...)`.

Comment: On this data, speed is irrelevant - both will be near instantaneous. The question is what's faster on data big enough for the difference to be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is close, but by making `Row` unique across all rows, you are guaranteeing that those rows will not really "join" the way you intend. Instead, number them within `VAR` and then spread:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
group_by(df, VAR) %>%
  mutate(Row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(VAR, Ranking)
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#     Row    X1    X2    X3
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   1.0   1.5    NA
# 2     2   2.5    NA    NA
# 3     3   2.5   1.0   1.5
# 4     4   1.5    NA   1.5
# 5     5    NA    NA   3.0
```

Comment: I actually implemented this variant but I accepted the "base" solution. Thank you